# OpenLayer2 - center map based on lon/lat of POI

Tags: openlayers-2

Is it possible to center the map to the coordinates of a POI, imported by using a text file? (`OpenLayers.Layer.Text`)

```
var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "My Points",
                { location:"./textfile.txt",
                  projection: toProjection
                });
map.addLayer(pois);

map.setCenter (????, zoom);
```

Comment: Do you mean a single POI, or the extent of the POI layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean to set the extent to the whole POI layer, then each [layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html) has a function [getExtent](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.getExtent):

> `getExtent: function()`
>
> Returns {OpenLayers.Bounds} A Bounds object
>   which represents the lon/lat bounds of the current viewPort.

You can use [getCenterLonLat](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.getCenterLonLat) to find the centre point of the bounds, and feed this to the map.setCenter function. Try something like this (not actually tested):

```
map.addLayer(pois);
var poiBounds = pois.getExtent();
var lonLat = poiBounds.getCenterLonLat()
map.setCenter (lonlat, zoom);
```

Comment: Stephen, 
It does not work for me. The getExtent()-function returns NULL. 

I used another solution, which does not do exactly the same, but is also suitable for me: 

map.zoomToExtent(poiLayer.getDataExtent());

Comment: @DirkVansina I'm not sure why your dataset would return null for `getExtent()` - but I'm glad you found a workaround using `getDataExtent()`. Since that also returns a `Bounds` object the `map.setCenter` approach may still work